# jQuery add class to generated div based on csv info

Tags: jquery, get, addclass

I have the following code

```
$.get('feed.txt', function(data) {
var arr = data.split('|');
var values = '';
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  values += '<div>'+arr[i]+'</div>';
}
$('div').html(values);
});
```

and I want to add a class to the generated div based on the info that is supplied by the text file (sample below) ie if the type="small" then I want to add class="small"

```
TYPE: Small, ID: 0001, RESPONSE DATE AND TIME: 2012-12-12 12:00, UNITNAME: Name, MEMO: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.|
TYPE: Medium, ID: 0002, RESPONSE DATE AND TIME: 2012-12-12 01:00, UNITNAME: Name, MEMO: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.|
TYPE: Large, ID: 0003, RESPONSE DATE AND TIME: 2012-12-12 02:00, UNITNAME: Name, MEMO : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.get('feed.txt', function(data) {
    var arr = data.split('|');
    var values = '';
    var type, className;
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        type = arr[i].split(',')[0];
        switch(type){
            case "TYPE: Small":
                className = 'small';
            break;
            case "TYPE: Medium":
                className = 'medium';
            break;
            case "TYPE: Large":
                className = 'large';
            break;
        }
        values += '<div class="'+className+'">'+arr[i]+'</div>';
    }
    $('div').html(values);
});
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that and it's nearly there but it gives all divs class="small". And please explain to me why "var type, className" is not "var type = className" Thanks a lot. Cheers

Comment: `var type, className` is just declaring 2 variables that will be used later in the script. I'm not sure why it would give all divs class small, it should work with the sample data you've provided.

Comment: Thanks Clark, I created a jsfiddle to show you what's happening but for the fiddle I had to bring in the data as a variable an it worked great then, The problem seems to be in the way the info is loaded via .get(). Here is the link - http://jsfiddle.net/dwqZc/3/

Comment: Unfortunately i don't think i can help you without more information about your whole system Clinton. Perhaps see if the sample data you've provided is indicative of the whole set of data? Maybe there are instances where the 'TYPE:' is not the first record? or is left undefined?